# Need to start a transaction before commit when disabling the price order on Order in a CRM 2011 plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I wrote a plugin that does this:

```
tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Order");
//retrieve the entity order as the input Entity
//get both the copies of the entity, and get the updated fields from the new one
var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
var oldEntity = Helpers.ActualEntity(new EntityReference("salesorder", entity.Id), service);

tracingService.Trace("Before cast");
//Early bound entity
var order = new salesorder(entity);
var oldOrder = new salesorder(oldEntity);


//if the orderprice is not locked return
if ((order.ispricelocked == false) || (oldOrder.ispricelocked == false))
    return;
else
//if the orderprice is locked, unlock it
{
    var req = new UnlockSalesOrderPricingRequest();
    req.SalesOrderId = order.Id;
    var resp = (UnlockSalesOrderPricingResponse)service.Execute(req);
}
```

When I execute it I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Need to start a transaction before commitDetail: 
>       <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
>         <ErrorCode>-2147220911</ErrorCode>
>         <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
>           <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
>             <d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
>             <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
>           
>         
>         Need to start a transaction before commit
>         2014-02-17T12:56:33.4886464Z

I checked the CRM trace and what I got is:

Crm Exception: Message: Need to start a transaction before commit, ErrorCode: -2147220911

Have you seen before?

Comment: What's the step configuration ?

Comment: Sync and Post execution

Answer (score 2):

I know two possible explanations:

1. You're swallowing a `FaultException`.

When a `FaultException` is *thrown* the execution drops out of the transaction, so if you swallow it (i.e. you are okay with the failure and just want to carry on) you're no longer allowed to use the `IOrganizationService` object (and the message you got is the way the CRM has to tell you).

2. You're missing something

Make sure all primary fields are filled, in the record you're handling and in *all* the eventually related fields. A *null* name in a related record often makes CRM go boom.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you where the problem is

```
  var Order = new salesorder(entity);
```

So it needs to be created before you can process further requests on it.

Check if the

```
      Order.Id is null or Guid.Empty
```

You first have to create Order entity.

Comment: the entity object is retrieved from the context and is not null (If it was the order.ispricelocked instruction would have raised a NullPointException)

Comment: what does the order = new salesorder(entity) does ??

Comment: Create an early bound entity from a late bound one